# Not in condition does not consider null in Oracle

Tags: oracle, null, notin

I have result set as follows

```
reg_no    name    grade
--------- ------- ------
1112      Muthu   A
1113      Vikki   B
1114      Murali  C
1115      Shankar null
```

I have checked the condition with not in

```
select * from grades where grade not in ('B','C')
```

But when executing query i have got only one record that have A grade. I didn't get the 4th row. Am stuck with this. How to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one proper way to check null existence is **IS NULL** and **IS NOT NULL**

```
select * from grades where grade not in ('B','C') or grade is null
```

Comment: Thank you piotr. But i have doubt on this. Why we need to check null and it doesn't return the result

Comment: You cannot compare null with other value, it produces null as result. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29

Comment: Thanks Piotr. It's very useful

Answer (score 0):

Check like this

```
select * from grades where nvl(grade,'?') not in ('B','C');
```

But this appropriate cannot use index on grafes,if exists.